# Updating select options using variable as placeholder in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

In my project a page can have one or more selects with options filled with database values, means select fields with different id's can have the same options.

For example:

```
<select id="set-0-costID">
    <option value="1">Name1</options>
    <option value="2">Name2</options>
    <option value="3">Name3</options>
</select>
<select id="set-1-costID">
    <option value="1">Name1</options>
    <option value="2">Name2</options>
    <option value="3">Name3</options>
</select>
```

If p.e. the text of option == 1 is changed in field with id "set-0-costID" I want to update all other fields with id "*costID" using Jquery.

This code works:

```
$("[id$='costID']").each(function(index, elem){
    var $el = $('#' + elem.id);
    $('#' + elem.id + ' option[value="1"]').text('Name1new');
    $el.selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

But I have to be more flexible and want to store all posible fieldnames in a dict and loop thru it.

This code doesn't work. No error, but the options are not updated.

```
var fields=['cost1ID', 'cost2ID']; var field_name="";
for (f in fields) {
    field_name = fields[f];  
    $("[id$=field_name]").each(function(index, elem){
        var $el = $('#' + elem.id);
        $('#' + elem.id + ' option[value="1"]').text('Name1new');
        $el.selectpicker("refresh");
    });
};
```

I guess Jquery interpretes field_name as the name to search for and not as variable.
How do I have to change my code to make it working?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that will resolve problem but try to replace :

```
$("[id$=field_name]").each(function(index, elem){
```

By :

```
$("[id$='"+field_name+"']").each(function(index, elem){
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but have you considered data attributes? It might make your code more flexible further down the line.

Here, I've created an attribute called `data-update`, which lists each ID to update (separated by a space):

```
<select id="set-0-costID" data-update="#set-1-costID #set-2-costID">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Name1</option>
    <option value="2">Name2</option>
</select>
<select id="set-1-costID" data-update="#set-0-costID #set-2-costID">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Name1</option>
    <option value="2">Name2</option>
</select>
<select id="set-2-costID" data-update="#set-0-costID #set-1-costID">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Name1</option>
    <option value="2">Name2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-update]', function(){
    var a = $(this).data('update').split(' '), index;
    for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
        $(a[index]).val( $(this).val() );
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo with IDs](http://jsfiddle.net/azd79g1u/)

This will also work with classes: [JSFiddle demo with classes](http://jsfiddle.net/azd79g1u/1/)